# If I run Visual Studio by appending /safemode no addons are loaded, visual studio is quick. So how do I get myself back there without an OS Reinstall?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, add-on

I have a quite a few addins installed on my Visual Studio 2012 and I am unhappy at the speed of the application now. I also have some other strange issues that I think are caused by 1 addin but I do not know which one.

I know Visual Studio has the add-in manager but that is not showing all addins that are loaded and running!

For example I have removed all check boxes but I am still getting addons loaded like Dev Express.

Is there any tools that let me see and remove addons - maybe a 3rd party tool someone has written?

If I run Visual Studio by appending /safemode no addons are loaded, visual studio is quick. So how do I get myself back there without an OS Reinstall?

How do I reset visual studio to the default state with no addons installed?

Or is there a known list of locations I can look at for installed addons?

Comment: Um... Disable all the addins? For DevExpress, all you should have to do is uninstall from Control Panel.

Comment: The problem is I want the products installed - It takes like an hour to install Dev Express and Telerik. I just want to find a way to  disable them so I can find what I want and what I do not. As more and more addons are available and install what ever they want I do not know what is causing the problems. I just want to properly disable them!

Comment: If they cannot be disabled in the usual way, you need to call Dev Express and Telerik.  Make sure you post an answer here, so that others can benefit.

Comment: I guess I may need to write something myself.

I think I am wanting to basically rename DLL's to _DLLs or Registry Keys so that the addon is not loaded but it is not deleted either. Amazing that others have not wanted or needed this functionality.